# Performance for finding the maximum value in a dictionary versus numpy array

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, numpy, max

I have a large (in thousands) collection of word : value (float) pairs. I need to find the best of the value and extract the corresponding associated word. For example, I have (a,2.4),(b,5.2),(c,1.2),(d,9.2),(e,6.3),(f,0.4). I would like (d,9.2) as the output.

Currently, I am using a dictionary to store these tuples and use the max operator to retrieve the maximum key value in the dictionary. I was wondering if a numpy array would be more efficient. Soliciting expert opinions here.

Comment: Do you need to store tuples in one structure or you can generate them on fly? If you need multiple maximum items, you can use 'heapq' http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html. What kind of problem you are solving and are you sure that this part is source of troubles?

Comment: I need to store the tuples in a structure. I just want to find the maximum numerical value and the corresponding 'key'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Numpy here would involve keeping the float values in a separate `ndarray`. Find the index of max value using `argmax` and get the word from a separate list. This is very fast, but constructing the ndarray only to find the max is not. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import operator

names = [str(x) for x in xrange(10000)]
values = [float(x) for x in xrange(10000)]
tuples = zip(names, values)
dic = dict(tuples)
npvalues = np.fromiter(values, np.float)

def fa():
    return names[npvalues.argmax()]

def fb():
    return max(tuples, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

def fc():
    return max(dic, key=dic.get)

def fd():
    v = np.fromiter((x[1] for x in tuples), np.float)
    return tuples[v.argmax()][0]
```

Timings: fa 67 µs, fb 2300 µs, fc 2580 µs, fd 3780 µs.

So, using Numpy (fa) is over 30 times faster than using a plain list (fb) or dictionary (fc), when the time to construct the Numpy array is not taken into account. (fd takes it into account)

Comment: *"I was wondering if a numpy array would be more efficient"*... and the answer is...?

Comment: @mac Added conclusion to the answer.

Comment: We really need more info from the OP to answer the question. He says he's currently using a dict store this word value pairs, is he willing to store them in an ndarray instead?

Comment: Bago, Yes I am willing to store this in an ndarray. The question I have for Janne is that would the Numpy > List/Dict still hold if Numpy array construction is taken into account?

Comment: @Denzil No, don't use a Numpy array if taking the max is the only use for it. In my examples, the fd function does just that, and it is the slowest.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see how a numpy array would help you in this case.

In particular, any conversion of a data structure into another (in your case a list of tuples in a numpy array or a heapq) will be much slower than finding the maximum value iterating over each tuple). This is because converting the data structure will also require to iterate over the original one, plus instantiating an object for the new structure, plus storing the value into the new structure, plus using the new structure to get the requested value.

Using a built-in function or method of your list will most probably result in a faster computation. The most trivial implementation I can think of:

```
>>> li = [('a',  10), ('b', 30), ('c', 20)]
>>> max(li, key=lambda e : e[1])[0]
'b'
```

Other possible ones if you are also interested in stuff like the lowest value or popping off the list the value you found could pass through sorting (so you examine the original list only once!):

```
>>> li = [('a',  10), ('b', 30), ('c', 20)]
>>> li.sort(key=lambda e : e[1])
>>> li
[('a', 10), ('c', 20), ('b', 30)]
>>> li[-1][0]
'b'
```

Or:

```
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda e: e[1])[-1][0]
'b'
```

HTH!

Comment: Mac, Thanks for the verbose reply. Note that the tuple can be constructed directly to a ndarray rather than first putting it in a dictionary and then converting to a ndarray. The example in the original post was just for demonstration.